# IE8 - jQuery addClass/removeClass not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

I have couple of links, like this:

```
<a href="" class="bluelink active-bold"><span data-id="..">Click Here</span></a>
<a href="" class="bluelink"><span data-id="..">No, Click Here</span></a>
```

I have a jquery click function, like this:

```
$("a > span").bind("click", function(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $("a").removeClass("active-bold");
    $(this).parents("a:first").addClass("active-bold");
    //$(this).parent().addClass("active-bold");
});
```

Works fine on all Firefox and Chrome, but not on IE8 or 9. There is no error in the console. If I step through the code, I see the code is being executed. But the changes are not being reflected in the page (ie, classes are not added/removed, like it happens in Chrome/FF). Tried to have the click event on anchor tags, did not work. It works if I have href="#", but can't have the page scroll to top. Any idea how to make this work on IE?

Thanks.

Comment: _jQuery 2.x has the same API as jQuery 1.x, but does not support Internet Explorer 6, 7, or 8_, make sure you're using 1.x

Comment: How exactly are the changes supposed to be reflected in the page?

Comment: I am using jquery 1.9.x

Comment: I created a fiddle with this code.  It works for me in IE9 and IE8 modes (I am using IE11).  [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/1e6htgo2/)

Comment: I am not able to open the jsfiddle page on IE8, due to js errors.